# Spring Boot configuration with Morphia?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, morphia

I do not want to utilize the Spring DATA MongoDB support.
I want to leverage the ORM for MongoDB called Morphia.

https://github.com/mongodb/morphia

I want to configure the Morphia with Spring Boot. I want to externalize the configuration of Morphia in a way that it follows the Spring Boot philosophy.

I want to leverage the environment variables for the configuration of Morphia properties.

What would be the Spring Boot approach to achieve this ?

In a simple main program on would do following to get the Morhpia ORM working.

```
private Morphia morphia; 
private MongoClient mongoClient; 

morphia = new Morphia();
// Person is an entity object with Morphia annotations
morphia.map(Person.class);

// THESE properties MUST be read from environment variables in Spring BOOT.
final String host = "localhost";
final int port = 27017;

mongoClient = new MongoClient(host, port);

//Set database
// this instance would be autowired all data access classes
Datastore ds  = morphia.createDatastore(mongoClient, "dataStoreInstanceId");

// this is how instance would be used in those data accesses classes
Person p = ds.find(Person.class, "username", "john").get();
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Spring Boot like approach would be to create a AutoConfiguration with the needed properties which creates an instance of `Datastore` as bean.

In the [Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-mongodb) you will find how to set properties and connect to a MongoDB.

An AutoConfiguration for Morphia could look like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MorphiaAutoConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private MongoClient mongoClient; // created from MongoAutoConfiguration

    @Bean
    public Datastore datastore() {
        Morphia morphia = new Morphia();

        // map entities, there is maybe a better way to find and map all entities
        ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider entityScanner = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(true);
        entityScanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(Entity.class));
        for (BeanDefinition candidate : scanner.findCandidateComponents("your.basepackage")) { // from properties?
            morphia.map(Class.forName(candidate.getBeanClassName()));
        }

        return morphia.createDatastore(mongoClient, "dataStoreInstanceId"); // "dataStoreInstanceId" may come from properties?
    }
}
```

You could then autowire your Datastore in other Spring beans the usual way:

```
    @Autowired
    private Datastore datastore;
```

If some points are not correct or unclear just take a look at the existing `*AutoConfiguration` classes in Spring Boot.

Comment: My primary concern was not to use Spring DATA which actually powers the  MongoAutoConfiguration, I wanted an approach independent  of spring data dependency .

If there is not conflict between Spring Data and Moprhia, then I'm OK with your approach.

What say ?

Comment: Ok, then you would inject the `MongoProperties` instead of a `MongoClient` into the AutoConfiguration and create a MongoClient with `MongoProperties.createMongoClient()` by yourself. You may need a `@EnableConfigurationProperties(MongoProperties.class)`. Then you are independent of Spring Data.

Comment: By looking at the `MongoAutoConfiguration` I would say that my original solution is also possible without a dependency to Spring Data. This applies automatically when MongoDB is in the classpath.

Comment: I'm getting an error even though I implemented it just as you said. Do you know what I have to do? Field mongoClient in MorphiaAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'com.mongodb.MongoClient' that could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working in a starter for spring boot, here is the [repo.](https://github.com/ganchix/morphia-spring-boot-starter) Is very easy to use, in some days will update it in maven central.