# MongoAutoConfiguration does not create MongoClient bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, morphia

I have just read [Spring Boot configuration with Morphia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29365535/spring-boot-configuration-with-morphia)
and I am trying to implement it like this. But I always get

```
Field mongoClient in MorphiaAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'com.mongodb.MongoClient' that could not be found.
```

If I understood the documentation correctly, a MongoClient bean should have been created automatically by the MongoAutoConfiguration.
Because I did not deactivate this configuration, it should be loaded due to my @SpringBootApplication annotation on my Main class. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Enable the [`debug` property](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.spring-application.startup-failure), then the condition evaluation report output to the console should show why the Mongo auto-configuration did not execute.

Comment: What is your spring boot version and your morphia version?

Comment: Using Spring Boot 2.6.6 and Morphia 1.6.1

Comment: I can see some debug logs now. But they don't help me find the issue here. It says "found required class 'com.mongodb.client.MongoClient'" which sounds good to me.

Comment: It does not sound good. Notice MongoClient is in another package. This is due to a fact that MongoDb repackaged it's artifacts. You need to use Morphia compatible with your MongoDb client version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything does work if I use Morphia 2.2.6. Just in case someone wants to know the details, I will explain what has been bothering me here.

My old version used `'dev.morphia.morphia:core:1.6.1'` and this class

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient; // Bad example; this code will not run!
import dev.morphia.Datastore;
import dev.morphia.Morphia;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class MorphiaAutoConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  private MongoClient mongoClient; // will not be created from MongoAutoConfiguration !!!!!

  @Bean
  public Datastore datastore() {
    return new Morphia().createDatastore(mongoClient, "mongodb");
  }
}
```

Now i'm using `'dev.morphia.morphia:morphia-core:2.2.6'` and

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import dev.morphia.Datastore;
import dev.morphia.Morphia;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class MorphiaAutoConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  private MongoClient mongoClient; // created from MongoAutoConfiguration

  @Bean
  public Datastore datastore() {
    return Morphia.createDatastore(mongoClient, "mongodb");
  }
}
```

Note that the MongoClient comes from another package. So my services has provided a `com.mongodb.client.MongoClient` Bean but no `com.mongodb.MongoClient` Bean, hence my confusion.